# Save file to dropbox from iphone app

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to save a file to dropbox with a url from my iphone app?

I have already added support for sending the file as an attachment from the mail, but it would be cool if the user could choose if he/she wants to save it in dropbox as well, if the application is present on the device.

So could this be done?

Comment: There might be a way to do it using some fancy URLS and `[UIApplication openURL:]`, but I really do suggest using the API instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to do such a thing is probably to use Dropbox [Objective-C API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/releases)

Answer (score 3):

```
NSString *localPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Info" ofType:@"plist"];
NSString *filename = @"Info.plist";
NSString *destDir = @"/";
[[self restClient] uploadFile:filename toPath:destDir
                   withParentRev:nil fromPath:localPath];
```

In this way u can save any file in the Dropbox.

Answer (score 1):

yes its possible , Check this link - will help you to start with the Dropbox APi

http://www.nanaimostudio.com/blog/2011/1/20/how-to-synchronize-your-app-data-using-dropbox-api.html

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone gets here looking to do this from the iPhone, but not programmatically within an app, here are some handy services:

- http://urlpipe.com/ - oauth, one folder
- http://urldroplet.com/ - oauth, full Dropbox
- https://www.sidecloudload.com/ - login/pass - full access